# NoClassDefFoundError for Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss

Why do i get a run time error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I could able to compile it but unable to run my simple servlet program on Jboss.

I did Google it for solution but nothing helped me out.

Please advice!

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your class is available at build time but not at runetime. Look for the the differences in your build time and runtime class path.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about build time and runtime class path, PLEASE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270950/compile-time-vs-run-time-dependency-java. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for giving the reference, It helped-:)

Answer (score 0):

it seems the servlet class you have specified in web.xml is not full qualified. 
OR provide more detail of exception and code.