# When is a time to use Run-time over Compile-time dependencies in Java/Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, runtime, compile-time

From my understanding Gradle will carry over all `compile` dependencies as `runtime` dependencies.

What is an instance when you should only use `runtime`? All child dependencies are grabbed from `compile` and pulled into the compilation when `gradle build` is called.

For example, when I do a diff on what is printed when I call

```
> gradle -q dependencies
```

The list printed out for **compile** and **runtime** are identical. Example output may show following for both:

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: -> 1.5.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.9.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
```

I have looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270950/compile-time-vs-run-time-dependency-java#4272424) which helped explain a little about the difference between **compile** and **runtime**, but it only showed that runtime is when your code actually executes a dependency. When would you have a **runtime** dependency, but not a **compile** time?

Comment: In our spring-boot application, we write log messages using slf4j. At runtime, slf4j is binded with log4j2 and log4j2 uses a configuration file to output our logs to a file. So slf4j is a compile time dependency, and log4j2 is a runtime dependency in this case.

Comment: I think I might understand now. So in my project I did not set up a logger. If I did, log4j2 could be set up as a `runtime` dependency because Spring or slf4j uses dependency injection (at runtime) to resolve that logger. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile time vs Run time Dependency - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270950/compile-time-vs-run-time-dependency-java)

Comment: @lu.koerfer, I have looked at that and included it in my question. It didn't answer everything I had questions about. In essence, when do you use compile time vs runtime in your gradle file.

Comment: Also this response helped me find use cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842742/when-would-i-need-maven-dependency-with-runtime-scope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A typical case involves dynamically creating classes via reflection. As a contrived example, consider this app:

```
package net.codetojoy;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class c = Class.forName("org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils");
        Object object = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
        System.out.println("object is : " + object);
    }
}
```

It will create an object of `StringUtils` from Apache Commons Lang. (This example is silly; consider a case where `libA` will effectively do this for classes in `libB`).

There is no compile-time dependency so there is no reason to burden the compile-time classpath with the jar. However at run-time, the jar is certainly required. The `build.gradle` file is below. It uses the `application` plugin which nicely bundles the dependencies into a runnable deliverable.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    runtime group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'
}

mainClassName = 'net.codetojoy.App'
```

Example output:

```
$ gradle run -q
object is : org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils@4aa298b7
```

Comment: This is a good example and helps, thanks! One follow up question: would dependency injection / @Autowire annotation be another example where you might have a runtime dependency? Like if an implementation class is in a different package than an interface that is in your compile time libraries?

Comment: Well, I would qualify the statement a bit and say that, yes, annotations that search the classpath at run-time would fall into this category. I can't really remember the @Autowire mechanism but I believe it is an example. Hopefully others will correct me here if I'm wrong.