# Unable to run Jmeter 3.3 after updating core.jar in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a custom plugin for jmeter 2.13 earlier when I was creating a jar of the core package from the version 2.13 and using that jar in version 3.3 it was running fine Jmeter 3.3 was getting launched and all the functionalities were working fine but now when I am doing the same and starting the Jmeter.bat after updating the core.jar jmeter in jmeter 3.3, jmeter 2.13 is being launched.

How is the version being determined from the core jar?

One more thing I was trying to build the Jmeter 5.4.3 and 3.3 source code but there were lot of error due to jar dependencies I am feed up with removing the jar dependencies as due to different jar versions not supporting a set of methods.

What is the best way to build Jmeter 5.4.3 source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the version being determined from the core jar?

As of [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) the version is being returned by [`JMeterVersion.getVERSION()`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/core/src/main/version/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterVersion.java#L29) function

The same for [JMeter 3.3](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v3_3/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterVersion.java#L100)

> What is the best way to build Jmeter 5.4.3 source code

it's [sufficient to invoke `./gradlew build` command](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html) from the unpacked [JMeter source bundle](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi#source)

With regards to your version mismatch problem take a look at [compile time and run time dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270950/compile-time-vs-run-time-dependency-java) concept, most probably you created some form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) due to your plugin "fat" jar includes JMeter core and it shouldn't be the case.

More information:

- [How to Write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf)
- [How to Develop a JMeter Plugin: Intro & Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices)